# How much time does the average professional singer spend with a vocal coach?

Tags: practice, voice

I spend an hour every week with my vocal coach. I'm guessing that professional singers do warmups and such almost every day, but how much time a week on average do they spend with their vocal coach? Assuming my voice and wallet could handle it, I'd be doing it 40hrs a week! My coach said even Celine Dion still does regular vocal coaching? Curious how much time others spend with their coach?

Comment: I seem to have differing impressions of "voice teacher" and "vocal coach" -- personally I would say the voice teacher is the person I meet with every week, and a vocal coach might be hired by a production to work with a number of singers for a limited time... but the terms are probably interchangeable to a certain degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know two people who sing for a living.  Neither of them have had a vocal coach since college (approximately 10 years).  During high school, they had two two-hour sessions each week.  During college, the training was more intense.  Each of them said that they spent probably twenty to thirty hours a week in private and classroom instruction.  Both of these guys are top level and have masters degrees in music.  Both of them spend ten hours each week giving private lessons now and they say that it keeps their own skills very sharp.  They recommend two two-hour sessions a week as a minimum.